# Don't show PHP form action page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a page that sends an image through email using an HTML form. It functions great, but when user click SEND EMAIL, it shows the whole action behind the send.php page. How can I hide this from the user. It would be great if I can just have some text appear on the page that says "Your Message has been Sent!!!".

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="email/send.php">
    <input type=button value="Take HD Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send Email">
</form>
```

The SEND.PHP is below. It is a PHPMAILER plugin.

```
<?php
/**
 * This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
 */
//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'mail_server';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('mail_server');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;
//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "username";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "password";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('username', 'Name');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('Name', 'Name');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('Name', 'Name');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Add an Attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("../snapshots/image.jpg");
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

Comment: You can use AJAX for sending mail. And on AJAX response, you can show the success message.

Comment: whats in send.php? and NO you dont need ajax

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant php code. You can remove the unwanted outputs from the php code

Comment: show your send.php code, you need to use redirection in this file after success.

Comment: and you can also follow as like Take HD Snapshot, here u are using a javascript event ...

Comment: I just added the PHP code. When it goes through successfully, it shows like 500 lines of garble, then at the end of it all it says "Message Sent". I would like it to NOT show all the unnecessary garble.

Comment: @MariaNolorbe: yes we have checked, you need to redirect on success page..

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change the PHPMAILER to not include debugging

$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; (It was on 1)